# Why are there no teller transactions?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any *in-universe* reason why Gringotts forces its customers to ride a minecart to room-sized safety deposit boxes in order to deposit/withdraw money, rather than allowing them to deposit/withdraw money with the tellers?

Comment: It's more like a safe deposit box than a bank account. They wouldn't be allowed to fetch your items from such a box in reality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in canon to say that Gringotts doesn't offer ordinary accounts too.  But the use of vaults is traditional in wizarding society, so if you have one you're going to use it.

Note that all the people we see or hear of using Gringotts in canon are either wealthy, of pureblood descent, or both.  Those who can't afford to buy a vault, and didn't inherit one, however, may well use simple accounts: we just never see it in person.

The scene in *Philosopher's Stone* where we are introduced to Gringotts certainly suggests that ordinary accounts are available:

> About a hundred more goblins were sitting on high stools behind a long counter, scribbling in large ledgers, weighing coins in brass scales, examining precious stones through eyeglasses.

Also, from *Deathly Hallows*:

> "But I thought we were looking for places You-Know-Who's been, places he's done something important?" said Ron, looking baffled.  "Was he ever inside the Lestranges' vault?"
>
> "I don't know whether he was ever inside Gringotts," said Harry.  "He never had gold there when he was younger, because nobody left him anything.  He would have seen the bank from the outside, though, the first time he ever went to Diagon Alley."
>
> Harry's scar throbbed, but he ignored it; he wanted Ron and Hermione to understand about Gringotts before they spoke to Olleander.
>
> "I think he would have envied anyone who had a key to a Gringotts vault.  I think he'd have seen it as a real symbol of belonging to the wizarding world. [...]"

Answer (score 3):

**Don’t think of Gringotts as a bank; think of it as a safety-deposit box.**

Most of the transactions we see are strictly monetary, and indeed, goblins can get money directly from a vault for you – witness, for example, Sirius’s remote withdrawal to buy Harry’s Firebolt – but plenty of the vaults contain more than just money. Treasure, artefacts, precious objects – which should only be retrieved by their owner directly.

If you look at safety deposits in real life, you normally have direct access to the box. It would be unusual for a member of staff to retrieve items on your behalf – it’s just that safety deposit boxes are much smaller than a bank vault.

Remember also that wizards and goblins don’t trust each other. If both parties are present for the opening of the vault, there’s less room for accusations of impropriety or cheating – on either side.

---

For pure monetary transactions, there are ATMs (although they’re of questionable canon status):

- In *The Wizarding World of Harry Potter*, [there’s a “Gringotts Automated Teller Machine”](http://www.parksleuth.com/photos/?album=1&photo=164&occur=1):

  [image]

  Closer inspection reveals that it’s been charmed, so it appears to dispense Muggle money – a neat trick to throw us simpletons off the scent!
- In the GameBoy Color edition of the *Chamber of Secrets* game, Harry complains that there aren’t any ATMs in Diagon Alley.

Since ATMs seem to exist, it’s possible you could do teller transactions in-person. But once you’ve got all the way to the bank, I imagine they’d prefer you go to the vault (to avoid any funny business).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a good explanation why the above protocol is followed in Gringotts Bank and not the normal muggle banking protocols.

The simple reason is - There are many other (sometimes DARK) things in the room-sized safety deposits apart from just Galleons, Sickles and Knuts.

The Lestranges locker, for instance, contained many Dark Objects, Family Jewels, Goblin made Gryffindor Sword, Vodemort's Horcruxes (perhaps Bella didn't know what it was - to her it was a simple golden cup, nevertheless)..but I believe you get the drift.

The users of the Gringotts would not want any of the bank employee to enter their personal chamber on their behalf and take/put money. Even if one deposit the money or take the money from the teller upstairs, the money eventually will be put/taken from the locker which I don't think anyone would want to be open without their consent in their absence.